# vscode typescript inline error is not showing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

i am using vs code for typescript and the inline errors are not showing. but it only shows when complied.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t338f.png)

errors:
line 1 => remove type annotation
line 2 => str is assigned a value but never used

from my understanding, since str is is a string there should be an error on line number 2 saying "type string is not assignable to type number" but there is none.

what can i do to make inline errors show up?

i have installed eslint, nodemon, set up my tsconfig and still inline errors are not showing.

i have also set my settings.json to
`"typescript.validate.enable": true,`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've been having exactly this issue for weeks now, but only on TS versions from 5.*.  I get inline errors only on 4.9.5 and below, which is frustrating because obviously I want to use 5.  I get no type errors whatsoever showing up inline when using version 5, and it's bizzare.  I can also reproduce it on the online version of vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

so the problem was in my user settings.json file

i changed my settings.json to empty curly brackets
`{}`

and reloaded vs code then the inline error appeared.

im not sure what is causing the error in my previous json settings but its solved.